# how thread execute inside for-loop

Tags: for-loop, threadpoolexecutor, executor

If we have below code, is for-loop will wait until runner complete its work then go from i=0 to i=1 or not ?
how this code will execute?

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) { 
                Runnable runner = new RevokGrantTask(token, threadAttachments, currentUserID, userId, true); 
                log.info("Adding: " + thread); 
                executor.execute(runner); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are submitting 5 tasks here through the loop.its not like , finish one task and then go to next .5 tasks will be submitted and order of results could not be necessarily not in order.